# How to find out the min value of the third field according to the first two fields using awk

Tags: bash, awk

The ontent of file named `test.file` is as follows:

```
333379266       834640619       88
333379280       834640621       99
333379280       834640621       66
333376672       857526666       99
333376672       857526666       78
333376672       857526666       62
```

The first two columns may be duplicate, and I want to output the first two columns and the corresponding min value of the third column.In this case,The result file should be as follows:

```
333379280 834640621 66
333379266 834640619 88
333376672 857526666 62
```

My attemp is:

`awk '{a[$1" "$2]=99999;a[$1" "$2]=a[$1" "$2]<$3?a[$1" "$2]:$3}END{for(i in a) print i,a[i]}' test.file`

My question is:

Is there any `other way` to achieve this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following to look for minimum values for 1st and 2nd field keys in whole Input_file.

```
awk '
{
  ind=$1 OFS $2
  array[ind]=(array[ind]<$3?(array[ind]?array[ind]:$3):$3)
}
END{
  for(i in array){
     print i,array[i]
  }
}'  Input_file
```

OR as per @kent's comments adding following solution with an additional condition to check for null value in 3rd field as follows.

```
awk '
{
  ind=$1 OFS $2
  array[ind]=(array[ind]<$3||array[ind]==""?(array[ind]?array[ind]:$3):$3)
}
END{
  for(i in array){
     print i,array[i]
  }
}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '                                                                ##Starting awk program from here.
{
  ind=$1 OFS $2                                                      ##Creating variable ind whose value is 1st and 2nd field.
  array[ind]=(array[ind]<$3?(array[ind]?array[ind]:$3):$3)           ##Creating array with index of variable ind and checking if its value is lesser than $3 then keep it same else assign $3 to it.
}
END{                                                                 ##Starting END block for this awk program here.
  for(i in array){                                                   ##Traversing through all elements of array here.
     print i,array[i]                                                ##Printing key of array and value of array here.
  }
}'  Input_file                                                       ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```